# Student's Age in Fictional Stats Class Problem (Probability)

Tags: probability

**Problem:**

In a fictional stats class, 40% of students are female, and the rest are male. Of the female students, 30% are less than 20 years old and 90% are less than 30 years old. Of the male students, half are less than 20 years old and 70% are less than 30 years old.

(a) Make a **contingency table** to describe these two variables

(b) Find the **probability** that a randomly selected studet is 30 years or older

(c) If a student is 20 years or older, what is the **probability** that the student is female?

(d) If a student is less than 30 years old, what is the **probability** that the student is 20 years or older?

---

**My Thoughts:**

(b) P(<30 years) = 1 - 0.78 = 0.22

(c) What I first did was find P(S2 given 'not A1'), but the answer doesn't make sense because the denominator ended up being smaller than the nominator.

(d) Do I solve this problem by doing 'not 20 years'?

Comment: First from the question, the group "less than 20" and "less than 30" are not mutually exclusive. For the contingency table, probably you should have "less than 20", "between 20 and 30" and "above 30" as the 3 age groups. You try to figure out the table again first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow @BGM's suggestion in the comments.

Let $F$ denote female; let $M$ denote male; let $A$ denote age.

Since $40\%$ of the students are female and $30\%$ of them are less than $20$ years old, the probability that a student is female and less than $20$ years old is 
$$P(F~\cap A < 20) = P(F)P(A < 20 \mid F) = 0.40 \cdot 0.30 = 0.12$$
Since $90\%$ of the female students are less than $30$ years old, the probability that a student is female and less than $30$ years old is 
$$P(F~\cap A < 30) = P(F)P(A < 30 \mid F) = 0.40 \cdot 0.90 = 0.36$$
The probability that a student is female, at least $20$ years old, and less than $30$ years old can be found by subtracting the probability that she is less than $20$ years old from the probability that she is less than $30$ years old, which yields
$$P(F~\cap 20 \leq A \leq 30) = P(F~\cap A < 30) - P(F~\cap A < 20) = 0.36 - 0.12 = 0.24$$
Finally, the probability that a student is female and at least $30$ years old is found by subtracting the probability that a student is female and less than $30$ years old from the probability that a student is female, which yields
$$P(F~\cap A \geq 30) = P(F) - P(F~\cap A < 30) = 0.40 - 0.36 = 0.04$$

By using similar reasoning, we can fill in the table for the male students.

$$
\begin{array}{l | c | c | c | c}
  & A < 20 & 20 \leq A < 30 & A \geq 30 & Total\\ \hline
F & 0.12 & 0.24 & 0.04 & 0.40\\
M & 0.30 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.60\\ \hline
Total & 0.42 & 0.36 & 0.22 & 1 
\end{array}
$$

The probability that a student is at least $30$ years old is stated in the contingency table.

To find the probability that a student who is at least $20$ years old is female, divide the probability that a female student is at least $20$ years old by the probability that a student is at least $20$ years old, both of which can be found by adding the appropriate columns in the table.

The probability that a student who is less than $30$ years old is at least $20$ years old can be found by subtracting the probability that the student is less than $20$ years old from the probability the student is less than $30$ years old.  To find the probability that a student is less than $30$ years old, you can subtract the probability that a student is greater than $30$ years old from $1$.